# I did not get the hat for answering my own question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

Yesterday I answered my own question but I did not receive the corresponding hat.

I also undeleted a question but did not get the corresponding hat.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I think you should both ask and answer the question during winterbash. You [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19977497/447356) over a month ago, long before winterbash began.

Comment: I undeleted a question yesterday and answered it as well.

Comment: Not relevant, what matters is the original time of posting it. You'll have to write new question and answer it to get the hat. (not 100% sure about it, but that sounds likely)

Comment: Was that your own question? Chances are [Reanimated](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/reanimated) requires you to undelete a question that is not your own.

Comment: Yes it was mine. But I answered it yesterday so I should have gotten the hat for answering it.

Comment: @AdamArold you undeleted it yesterday, but when did you ask it?  The undeletion event doesn't matter, it is when the question was asked.

Comment: It was asked weeks ago but I **answered it yesterday**.

Comment: But as @ShaWizDowArd said initially, we believe you have to ask and answer the post during winter bash.

Comment: Why the downvote? You ruined my chances for today :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, I have to ask and answer my question during Winterbash.

Comment: With at least score of 1 on both Q&A.

Comment: Oh, I see. Details details.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Sockpuppet badge, you must both ask and answer the question during WinterBash.